# Simple birthday program? Java

Tags: java, calendar, date

I'm trying to write a program that you simply enter your birthday as values (as in user input) , and you get something like

Months:
Day:
Year:

Here's my actual code for it so far:

```
public class DOB {
    private String days;
    private String months;
    private String years;

    private DOB() {

    }

    public DOB(int day, int month, int year)
    {
        this.days = day;
        this.months = month;
        this.years = year;
    }

    public int getDays()
    {
        return this.days;
    }

    public int getMonths()
    {
        return this.months;
    }

    public int getYears()
    {
        return this.years;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Month: " + months + "Day: " + days + "Year: " + days;
    }
}
```

I then also want to return the end result to another class called "Player.java".

I can't tell what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: "_I can't tell what I'm doing wrong._" What makes you think you are doing something wrong? Are there errors? Unexpected output?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Voting to close as unclear, as there is no programming problem.

Answer (score 1):

The code wouldn't compile as there are assignment problems of `int` to `String` and vice versa.

```
    private String days;
    //...
    public DOB(int day, int month, int year)
    {
        this.days = day; //assigning int to String

    }
    //...
    public int getDays()
    {
        return this.days; //returning String while method return type is int
    }
```

There are lot of options how to fix it, e.g. change constructor variables type to `String` and make getters return `String`, change everything to `int`.

But I suggest you to use existing Java Time API, there is a class having everything you need and even more, the `LocalDate`:

```
    LocalDate birthday = LocalDate.of(1980, 4, 25); 
    System.out.println(birthday.toString()); //displays 1980-04-25
    //Or get needed values directly
    int year = birthday.getYear(); //1980
    int month = birthday.getDayOfMonth(); //25
    int day = birthday.getMonthValue(); //4
```

There is a nice article on this topic specifically for beginners https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to print the age based on the given year, month and day of month as well as based on the current day / day of execution, do this using `java.time`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // assuming today as 2020-01-07
    printAge(2000, 1, 7);   // exactly 20 years
    printAge(1999, 12, 31); // 20 years and a week
    printAge(2000, 1, 8);   // 19 years, 11 months and 30 days
}

public static void printAge(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
    // create the birthday
    LocalDate birthday = LocalDate.of(year, month, dayOfMonth);
    // get today
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    // calculate the period between those two dates
    Period age = Period.between(birthday, today);
    // and print the resulting units of time
    System.out.println("The age today is " + age.getYears() + " years, "
            + age.getMonths() + " months and " + age.getDays() + " days");
}
```

The output on January, 7th 2020 will be

```
The age today is 20 years, 0 months and 0 days
The age today is 20 years, 0 months and 7 days
The age today is 19 years, 11 months and 30 days
```